# Wordpress REST API Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around Wordpress and its relation to the REST API. All of theses issues are only occurring in the context of plugin development. So far I had setup my endpoint and written my callback which will be executed whenever someone is sending a GET-Request to said endpoint. However, my callback is never called. This is the file which I've written so far.

```
  /*
   * Plugin Name: cola-learning
  */

  if(!defined('ABSPATH')){
      die;
  }

  if(!function_exists('add_action')){
      echo 'You cant access this ressource!';
      exit;
  }

  function PrintRESTResponse()
  {
      return rest_ensure_response("student");
  }

  function SetupREST()
  {
      return register_rest_route("student/v1","/view/",[
          'methods' => 'GET',
          'callback' => 'PrintRESTResponse'
      ],false);
  } 

  add_action('rest_api_init','SetupREST');
```

Perhaps it might also help, if I'll give some background information about my development machine:
- OS: Windows 10
- Server: Apache Web Server (included inside XAMPP)
- Wordpress Version: 5.3.2
- PHP Version: 7.4
- Development IDE: Eclipse 2019-12 CDT ( with PHP Plugin )

From my research, everything should work fine. However, it doesnt :/ Did I miss something crucial?

**Update:**

**WordPress REST API Routing**

WordPress is having a default route for all request which are directed to the REST API ( at least if you use XAMPP with the Bitnami WordPress application module). Now, if one wants to send a request to said REST API, the person needs to use an URL with the form of *ip:port/wp-json/rest_route*. *ip* ressembles the ip address of the server which is hosting wordpress. *port* is the port of said server. *wp-json*, however, is the portion which differs an ordinary request from a request to the REST API. Everything after this portion (*rest_route*) is the rest route which I've defined in the above source code.

**What went wrong?**

My request was pointed to the wrong endpoint. Therefore I used the URL 'localhost:wpPort/wordpress/student/v1/view/'. However, the 'wp-json/' portion is missing. Therefore WordPress will search for a page that doesn't exist in the first place. Instead I should have used the URL 'localhost:wpPort/wordpress/wp-json/student/v1/view/'.

Comment: I'm not seeing it in your code sample so I think you need to attach your function to the rest api init hook: `add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'SetupREST' );`

Comment: I accidentally forgot to include this portion. It should be inside the latest version of my answer.

Comment: Ok cool. Next thing I would try is move your code into your theme's functions file which would rule out any misconfiguration with the plugin.

Comment: One question: I'm developing a plugin, should I still move the code portion into the "theme's function file"? Still, I've tried your advice. So far nothings seems to be off inside WordPress.

Comment: Up to you. It's only a troubleshooting technique I use. What is the endpoint URL you're using to verify?

Comment: The URL is localhost:80/wordpress/student/v1/view/

Comment: Ahh try this: localhost:80/wordpress/wp-json/student/v1/view/

Comment: Yes, it's working now :) Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209181/discussion-between-jibran-and-ilikedcplusplus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting it turns out the URL being used to test was missing a part of the endpoint path.

Here is the correct path to test the newly registered endpoint.

```
localhost:80/wordpress/wp-json/student/v1/view/
```

Here's some more reading on WP Rest API endpoints:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/